# Unexpected OS Shutdown

Tags: windows-10, kernel, cpu, amd, shutdown

Recently I started to have an unexpected OS shutdown (Kernel Power Error 41) so I started to diagnose the cause. I noticed I also have Error Code 33 Shown By the Motherboard LED. In the motherboard manual, 32~36 is specified as CPU PEI initialization.

This is my system information:

```
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 19045)
System Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
System Model: AX370-Gaming K7
BIOS: F51i (type: UEFI)
Processor: AMD Ryzen 3 1200 Quad-Core Processor            (4 CPUs), ~3.1GHz
Memory: 16384MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 16306MB RAM
DirectX Version: DirectX 12
```

This is my display information:

```
Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070
Manufacturer: NVIDIA
Chip type: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070
```

I installed fresh Windows 10 and downloaded all updates, Also updated all drivers and the motherboard's bios but the problem still happening randomly. Sometimes PCs work for hours and sometimes shut down in a few minutes.

When pc shuts down, It won't turn on when I press the Power button on the case. I can see the motherboard has power since the power button on the motherboard and LAN slot have light. I have to switch off the power supply button and once the motherboard power is gone, Switch back on and press the power button on the case.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance